# how to get specific cell value from a html table based on checkbox selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have this dinamic data html table:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="table" id="tSortable">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th><input type="checkbox" name="checkall"/></th>
                                <th width="Auto">Adresa Unica</th>
                                <th width="Auto">ID</th>
                                <th width="Auto">Status</th>
                                <th width="Auto">Time</th>
                                <th width="Auto">Date</th>
                                <th width="Auto">Interval I</th> 
                                <th width="Auto">Duty</th>
                                <th width="Auto">Interval II</th>
                                <th width="Auto">Duty</th>
                                <th width="Auto">Interval III</th>
                                <th width="Auto">Duty</th>
                                <th width="Auto">Interval IV</th>
                                <th width="Auto">Duty</th>
                                <th width="Auto">Calendar</th>
                                <th width="Auto">Model</th>
                                <th width="Auto">Installation Address</th>                          
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                               <?php
                            while($griddata=mysql_fetch_assoc($records))
                            {

                                echo"<tr>";
                                echo "<td><input type='checkbox' class='ck'/></td>";
                                echo"<td class='mac'>".$griddata{'adresaUnica'}."</td>";
                                echo"<td>".$griddata{'id'}."</td>";
                                echo"<td class='a_i'>".$griddata{'status'}."</td>";
                                echo"<td>".$griddata{'time'}."</td>";
                                echo"<td>".$griddata{'date'}."</td>";
                                echo"<td>".$griddata{'interval1'}."</td>";
                                echo"<td class='duty'>".$griddata{'duty1'}."</td>";
                                echo"<td >".$griddata{'interval2'}."</td>";
                                echo"<td class='duty'>".$griddata{'duty2'}."</td>";
                                echo"<td>".$griddata{'interval3'}."</td>";
                                echo"<td class='duty'>".$griddata{'duty3'}."</td>";
                                echo"<td>".$griddata{'interval4'}."</td>";
                                echo"<td class='duty'>".$griddata{'duty4'}."</td>";
                                echo"<td>".$griddata{'calendar'}."</td>";
                                echo"<td>".$griddata{'model'}."</td>";
                                echo"<td>".$griddata{'adresainstalare'}."</td>";
                                echo"</tr>";
                            }
                                ?>


                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

and this code .js that i use to get an alert of all the values from the td's with the class "mac"

```
    $(  document).ready(function(e) 
{

 $('#tSortable td.mac').each(function() {
     var $this=$(this);
     var value= $this.text();
     alert(value);

});   

});
```

what i want is an example on how to get the value of that cell based on the checkbox that i select .?

Comment: Are you want that when user checked the checkbox, to alert the text inside the `.mac` td in the same `tr`?

Comment: yes Mosh Feu that is exactly what i want. Apparently the answers provided  are not so good.

Comment: See my answer. I hope that it will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's change function. The function is triggered when the state of the check boxes changes. Here is some example code:

```
// Triggers when a checkbox changes state
$('#tSortable td.mac').change(function() {

    // Checks if this object is selected
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        alert($(this).text());

        // You can also get a list of all siblings (The other TDs)
        $(this).siblings();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't bind `change` event to a `td` node.

Comment: in both cases the script works, it shows an alert box but there is no data inside? my table is dinamic data table. . any ideea why that happens?

Answer (score 0):

Use the change event, then a conditional to see if it is checked: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wrxsti85/ew75kwdt/)

```
$('body').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(e){
    if(this.checked) alert($(this).parent().next().text());
});
```

If you use dynamic elements remember to use event delegation by utilizing the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method.

Comment: By `dynamic` he meant that he render the table in the server not in the client. See his code.

Comment: @MoshFeu Yeah I understand that, but it is still an applicable answer, and event delegation is a common issue so I figured I would toss it in as an after thought.

Comment: i;ve tried the code above. it creates an alert box but is empty in my case. and yes my table is dynamic. . thank you for your kind answer.

Comment: How about in the fiddle demo? Is the alert blank there?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.ck').change(function() {
  // I deliberately using parents in case that some day you will reorder the columns
  var txt = $(this).parents('tr').first().find('.mac').text();
  $('#result').text('The text is: ' + txt);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="table" id="tSortable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" name="checkall" /></th>
            <th>Adresa Unica</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Interval I</th>
            <th>Duty</th>
            <th>Interval II</th>
            <th>Duty</th>
            <th>Interval III</th>
            <th>Duty</th>
            <th>Interval IV</th>
            <th>Duty</th>
            <th>Calendar</th>
            <th>Model</th>
            <th>Installation Address</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkOne" class="ck" /></td>
            <td class="mac">Adresa Unica____1</td>
            <td>ID____1</td>
            <td>Status____1</td>
            <td>Time____1</td>
            <td>Date____1</td>
            <td>Interval I____1</td>
            <td>Duty____1</td>
            <td>Interval II____1</td>
            <td>Duty____1</td>
            <td>Interval III____1</td>
            <td>Duty____1</td>
            <td>Interval IV____1</td>
            <td>Duty____1</td>
            <td>Calendar____1</td>
            <td>Model____1</td>
            <td>Installation Address____1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkOne" class="ck" /></td>
            <td class="mac">Adresa Unica____2</td>
            <td>ID____2</td>
            <td>Status____2</td>
            <td>Time____2</td>
            <td>Date____2</td>
            <td>Interval I____2</td>
            <td>Duty____2</td>
            <td>Interval II____2</td>
            <td>Duty____2</td>
            <td>Interval III____2</td>
            <td>Duty____2</td>
            <td>Interval IV____2</td>
            <td>Duty____2</td>
            <td>Calendar____2</td>
            <td>Model____2</td>
            <td>Installation Address____2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<hr />

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: I don't believe this accounts for the unchecking. A conditional could cover it. :)